# Divide Bootstrap card class to 3 horizontal boxes of the same size and 2 vertical boxes

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4 and I have the following Bootstrap code block:

```html
<div class="card-body text-success">

</div>
```

I need to create an image gallery: 3 horizontal boxes of the same size and 2 vertical boxes, so I tried the following code:

```html
<div class="card-body text-success">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            Your text
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            Your text
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            Your text
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            Your text
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            Your text
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            Your text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But this generates the gallery with some space between images. I need images without any space between. What could I do to achieve this?

Comment: Why not just add `p-0` class to the `col-4`, like: `<div class="col-4 p-0">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card-group flex-wrap">
  <div class="card border-0">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/10/03/14/54/rock-formations-5623735__340.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
  </div>
  <div class="card border-0">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/10/03/14/54/rock-formations-5623735__340.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
  </div>
  <div class="card border-0">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/10/03/14/54/rock-formations-5623735__340.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card-group flex-wrap">
  <div class="card border-0">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/10/03/14/54/rock-formations-5623735__340.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
  </div>
  <div class="card border-0">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/10/03/14/54/rock-formations-5623735__340.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
  </div>
  <div class="card border-0">
    <!-- this is empty space -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**CSS**

```css
.borders{
  border: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<div class="card-group">
    <img class="card-img-top card borders" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200">
    <img class="card-img-top card borders"  src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200">
    <img class="card-img-top card borders"  src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200">
</div>

<div class="card-group">
    <img class="card-img-top card borders" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200">
    <img class="card-img-top card borders"  src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200">
    <img class="card-img-top card borders"  src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200">
</div>
```

**[Preview Screenshort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCXw5.png)**

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider doing your gallery with plain CSS. Witch makes the HTML so much nicer:

```css
.gallery {
  width: 600px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  grid-gap: 0;
}
.gallery > * {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200?1" alt="">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200?2" alt="">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200?3" alt="">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200?4" alt="">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200?5" alt="">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200?6" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: this one is also fine

Comment: This solution also has the benefit, that the HTML doesn't dictate the number of columns.